# find foundation in memory

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I find Apple's Frameworks in the memory of my iOS-device using Objective-C code? For example, let's say I want to use some methods of the EventKit framework without directly accessing them, but by using function pointers with the memory location of the framework's method.

I know the location of the frameworks is randomised by ASLR but I assume you can still find the address.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I suggest a more skeptical `WHY...`!?

Comment: Thank you both for your questions. The reason is, I want to be able to dynamically call methods at runtime. At compile time, I don't know which methods I will use, but I know all the frameworks which may be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, unless the framework component you're after is in your app's address space. iOS is a protected OS, and memory address outside of your address space will trigger a memory protection fault and crash your app.

Many of the rules restricting access don't apply on jailbroken devices. It sounds like that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your response! So what if I include the frameworks I plan on accessing in the header? Will they be loaded in my app's address space?

If not, why can I access them using compiled ObjC code but not buy finding them in memory?

Comment: After working on this topics for quite a time, I'm afraid I have to say this answer is not correct. You can very well dynamically load framework components not included in your binary.